# Como funciona os comados "extends" e "block endblock" do Jinja2?

Tags: característica-linguagem, jinja2

Estou usando o Jinja2 para criar os templates para minha aplicação. No entanto, eu fiquei confuso em relação a duas funcionalidades dele.

As funcionalidades são:

O comando `extends`:

```
{% extends 'pagina-exemplo.html' %}
```

e o comando `block`:

```
{% block content %}

{% endblock  %}
```

Eu não sei muito bem como elas funcionam, ou como o mecanismo de herança de template funciona no que diz respeito a esses dois comandos.

## Pergunta

- Como funciona os comados `extends` e `block endblock` do Jinja2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tags `extends` e `block` funcionam em conjunto e servem para construir templates com ideias de herança, sobreposição e reuso.

Em um template você pode definir inúmeras tags `block`, as quais podem posteriormente ser sobrepostas ou reutilizadas por templates "filhos". Os filhos tem a intenção de utilizar os templates "pais" através do block `extends`, que importa o template e agora o filho passa a "ver" os blocos do pai. Os filhos irão **preencher** as tags `block` com o conteúdo desejado, ou mesmo reutilizar o que já está no pai com o comando `super`.

Aqui abaixo um exemplo completo retirado da documentação do Jinja2:

Arquivo `base.html` que será utilizado como template (pai) para os outros filhos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
        &copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo `child.html` que "estende" o pai `base.html`, sobrescreve alguns `block` que deseja e também utiliza porções do código do pai usando `super()`.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
      Welcome to my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Perceba o uso do comando `extends` antes de iniciar os blocos. É importante salientar que os blocos devem ser únicos no arquivo, ou seja, você não pode definir múltiplos blocos de mesmo nome. Essa limitação existe para que o filho saiba exatamente qual porção de bloco preencher. Além disso, caso queira reutilizar o **mesmo bloco** várias vezes no seu template, basta utilizar o comando `self.bloco()` onde `bloco()` é o nome do bloco que deseja reaproveitar.